# Python on Gentoo is missing sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, gentoo

I use a Gentoo-based Docker image for CI with multiple versions of Python. Recently, I've started experiencing errors because one tool (coveralls) requires sqlite, which is missing. sqlite is part of the Python standard library.

This can be checked from the command line

```
>>> removing all .pyc files
>>> executing command
me@5b35f99c08af /source $ python
Python 3.6.9 (default, Dec 27 2019, 12:15:49)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlite3'
```

I couldn't find any notes in the Gentoo packaging database about this, but I'm not really familiar with it as an OS. I assume there must have been a problem building some relevant library.

Python has been installed like this:
`RUN emerge -q -u dev-lang/python:3.6`

But the error occurs for all the versions I'm currently testing with: >= 3.5. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `sqlite3` (if I remember right) is optional when you build python from source. Thus I think that gentoo built did not include it. However, https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/dev-lang/python shows that sqlite is in the global use flags, so not 100% sure whats going on there. You can try `USE="sqlite" emerge -q -u dev-lang/python:3.6`

Comment: Can you also post the full traceback? sqlite is based on sqlite-dev being installed on the system

Comment: Is this a recent change to Gentoo's packaging? The image was last updated when Python 3.8 was released but the exception only started appearing 10 days or so ago.

Comment: sqlite-dev is not an option. Gentoo doesn't seem to split packages like Debian does, but specifying dev-db/sqlite did not make any difference,

Comment: @CharlieClark Did you try `USE="sqlite"` yet? You might need to add `-N` to `emerge` like `RUN USE="sqlite" -quN dev-lang/python:3.6`. The `-u` flag will tell `emerge` not to install the package if the latest version is not installed but `-N` tells it to reinstall it if the `USE` flags changed. So if the base Docker Gentoo image you are using has a newer Python installed, the `-u` might be preventing it from trying to install with your updated `USE` settings. Removing `-q` to make it louder and posting logs might help us debug too.

Comment: Yes, preprending `USE="sqlite"` does resolve the problemm though it doesn't look like this can be set as a global option. Will probably file a bug with Gentoo as this breaks things like coverage. :-/